# How to change font size, style of Shell/Terminal in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

This is what it shows in the config file:

```
"*":
  core:
    disabledPackages: [
      "atom-terminal"
    ]
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "atom-visual-studio-code-ui"
      "atom-dark-syntax"
    ]
  editor:
    fontSize: 17
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "1c14e-9c52-f7ffba987750"
  "platformio-ide-terminal":
    core:
      shell: "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
```

Also, the terminal looks like this
[image]
As you can see the blue color is barely visible. Also, I'd like to change the cursor to 'underline'.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Atom is built on top of the Chrome browser, you can use the built-in inspector to determine the styles of any element in the GUI. `platformio-ide-terminal` uses inline-styles and no "strong" CSS selectors.

Yet, you can override at least some of the styles. Use the inspector to get the selector of the element you want to change, that override the style in Atom's [user stylesheet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#style-tweaks) (`styles.less`).

**Example:**

```css
.platformio-ide-terminal.terminal-view .xterm > .terminal > div > span {
    color: @text-color-info !important;
}
```

PS: I've used what is *usually* the default blue of a UI theme (see [ui-variables](https://github.com/atom-community/ui-theme-template/blob/master/styles/ui-variables.less) for details)